# Why is loopback on Windows 10x slower than loopback within a Linux VM?

Tags: linux, windows, loopback

I have been testing the speed of my windows machine's loopback adapter using iperf3 which has given the following results:

[image: iperf3 results on windows]

However, when I run the exact same test within a linux virtual machine running on the same windows machine (using Oracle VM VirtualBox), I get the following results:

[image: iperf3 results on linux virtual machine]

This is a greater than 10-fold increase in throughput, which simply doesn't make sense. I would have assumed that the primary bottleneck for loopback traffic would be the CPU or RAM, but both tests were running on the exact same hardware, just with different operating systems.

My question is, what could be the cause of this discrepancy? Are these results typical for Windows/Linux respectively? Is there anything I can do to increase the throughput when running the test on windows?

I have tried disabling the firewall, and it made zero difference.

Comment: Why did you choose 127.0.0.1 for Windows and localhost for Linux? Shouldn't they be the same? Did you run iperf in Cygwin for Windows?

Comment: Try to disable security software such as antivirus.

Comment: How's the performance if the Windows is also in a VM?

Comment: Different OS, different stacks, etc.  Not sure why it's such a huge discrepancy though.  Maybe this link will help you https://serverfault.com/questions/234223/how-fast-is-127-0-0-1 and https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wincat/2012/12/05/fast-tcp-loopback-performance-and-low-latency-with-windows-server-2012-tcp-loopback-fast-path/

Comment: My colleague has already tried stripping away everything and starting from a blank windows installation. He managed to improve the loopback performance about 2-fold, but still nowhere close to the performance measured on linux. While I'm aware that different OSes will naturally have different performance, it remains unclear why there is such a massive gap between the two.

Comment: @AulisRonkainen the performance of windows in a VM was similar to windows outside the VM. Bad

Comment: Could the massive gap be explained by different stack implementation, which is in kernel?